# Serve Static Files on a Dynamic Route using Express

Tags: node.js, express

I want to serve static files as is commonly done with `express.static(static_path)` but on a dynamic
route as is commonly done with

```
app.get('/my/dynamic/:route', function(req, res){
    // serve stuff here
});
```

A solution is hinted at in this [comment](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/582#issuecomment-876792) by one of the developers but it isn't immediately clear to me what he means.

Comment: Did you try use instead of get:

app.use('/foo',express.static(__dirname+'/yourstaticdir'))

Comment: I actually want it to use dynamically matched urls, like /users/:id

Comment: Check out Sencha Lab's connect framework (what Express is built on top of), and take a look at its [`static`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html) middleware. Scroll way to the bottom of the middlware's page, and copy and paste the source code into your route. Hopefully from there, you can adapt it to serve static files like how the `static` middleware does it. Otherwise, just use `fs.readFile`.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Okay. I found an example in the source code for Express' [response object](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js). This is a slightly modified version of that example.

```
app.get('/user/:uid/files/*', function(req, res){
    var uid = req.params.uid,
        path = req.params[0] ? req.params[0] : 'index.html';
    res.sendFile(path, {root: './public'});
});
```

It uses the `res.sendFile` method.

**NOTE**: security changes to `sendFile` require the use of the `root` option.

Comment: You can't use `'../dir/' + file` because express thinks it's malicious user input (which is great).  Instead to send files relative to a certain directory use:

    `response.sendfile(file, {root: './dir/'})`

Comment: But how to render a specific page and pass page parameters in this case like `res.render(page, pageParameters)`?

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Make sure you also include the middleware to serve static files in express `app.use(express.static("./public"));` (not shown in answer)

Answer (score 17):

I use below code to serve the same static files requested by different urls:

```
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client/www'));
server.use('/en', express.static(__dirname + '/client/www'));
server.use('/zh', express.static(__dirname + '/client/www'));
```

Although this is not your case, it may help others who got here.

Comment: where does this answer fit with the "dynamic" part of URL parameters? I don't see how this is helping him serve static files from routes such as `/user/:uid` (notice the colon before **:uid**)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `res.sendfile` or you could still utilize `express.static`:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Dynamic path, but only match asset at specific segment.
app.use('/website/:foo/:bar/:asset', (req, res, next) => {
  req.url = req.params.asset; // <-- programmatically update url yourself
  express.static(__dirname + '/static')(req, res, next);
});         

// Or just the asset.
app.use('/website/*', (req, res, next) => {
  req.url = path.basename(req.originalUrl);
  express.static(__dirname + '/static')(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thx a lot!

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
app.use('/my/dynamic/:route', express.static('/static'));
app.get('/my/dynamic/:route', function(req, res){
    // serve stuff here
});
```

Documentation states that dynamic routes with `app.use()` works.
See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: This finally was the answer to my problem. It makes me wonder though why if I just have a standard `app.use(express.static('./public'));` middleware, why do we need to also have another `app.use('/viewVob/:id', express.static('./public'));` middleware for all the parameterized routes?