# Angular 2 Webpack Production Build & Node: can't get direct URLs to serve

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I followed the instructions to create a webpack build environment from the angular.io site: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html, and got it working. Then, I took the Tour of Heroes tutorial that I got working, and I migrated it to a webpack environment.

If I run the Tour of Heroes using the webpack dev environment (with `npm start`), it works great. If I then create a production build (with `npm run build`), and serve the resulting files with node, I cannot get the server to respond when I try to access a URL directly. Below I will outline the steps to create the environment and the problem step-by-step. I believe the solution is to modify my server.js file, but I don't know what is needed.

How to recreate:

1. Create the webpack build environment per the instructions on the website (link above).
2. Copy the `app` folder from the Tour of Heroes liteserver environment to the `src` folder of the webpack environment
3. In index.html of the webpack environment, comment out (or remove) all the scripts for polyfills and Configure SystemJS. Index.html should look like this:

   ```
   <html>
     <head>
       <base href="/">
       <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <!--
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
       <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
       <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
       <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
       <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
       <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
       <script>
         System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
       </script>
       -->
     </head>
     <!-- 3. Display the application -->
     <body>
       <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```
4. Modify the package.json so it has what is needed from both environments. Mine looks like this:

   ```
   {
     "name": "angular2-webpack",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "A webpack starter for Angular",
     "scripts": {
       "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
       "test": "karma start",
       "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail"
     },
     "licenses": [
       {
         "type": "MIT",
         "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
       }
     ],
     "dependencies": {
       "@angular/common": "~2.1.1",
       "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.1",
       "@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
       "@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
       "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
       "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.1",
       "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.1",
       "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
       "angular2-cool-storage": "^1.1.0",
       "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
       "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
       "core-js": "^2.4.1",
       "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
       "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
       "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
     },
     "devDependencies": {
       "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
       "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
       "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.35",
       "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
       "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
       "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
       "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
       "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
       "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
       "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
       "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
       "karma": "^1.2.0",
       "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
       "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
       "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
       "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
       "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
       "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
       "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
       "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
       "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
       "typescript": "^2.0.3",
       "webpack": "^1.13.0",
       "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
       "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0"
     }
   }
   ```
5. From the webpack folder, run `npm install`
6. From the webpack folder, run `npm run build` to create prod build files. This is what the webpack tutorial says to do.
7. Create a node server environment.
8. Create a server.js file at the root that looks like this:

   ```
   var express = require("express");

   var app = express();

   app.use(function(req, res, next) {
       console.log("Request recieved for:", req.url);
       next();
   });

   app.use(express.static('public'));

   app.use(function(req, res, next) {
       res.status(404);
       res.send('404 file not found');
   });

   app.listen(4040, function() {
       console.log("yes: 4040");
   });
   ```
9. In the node environment, create a `public` folder, and put all the files from the `dist` folder that was created in step 6 into the public folder.
10. Run the node server with `node server.js`
11. Go to localhost:4040. Everything works fine when accessed this way.
12. Enter this URL directly: `http://localhost:4040/heroes`
13. Get the 404 Error.
14. From the webpack environment if you run `npm start`, you can go to the URL directly `http://localhost:4040/heroes` and it works fine.

If you want to see all the code for this, here is the github repo: https://github.com/joshuaforman/heroeswebpack

Comment: Try changing the `<base href="/">` to `<base href="/heroes">` ?

Comment: What happens with `http://localhost:4040/#/heroes` ?

Comment: @Searching: it sends me to the page that is loaded if I were to enter only `http://localhost:4040` - in this case, the dashboard page. And what shows in the URL is `http://localhost:4040/dashboard#/heroes`. It does this no matter what I put in place of `heroes`. For instance, I can say `http://localhost:4040/blah`, and still go to the default page loaded, with this in the URL: `http://localhost:4040/dashboard#/blah`. So, closer to what I need, but not yet there. What is that `#` doing?

Comment: @ErtySeidohl : changing to `<base href="/heroes">` in the index.html file does not change the behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got it figured out. The issue was in the server.js. After more research, I found this: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html. Need to add more middleware after the express.static middleware: `app.use('/heroes', express.static('public'));`. The direct URLs work as needed with this server.js file:

```
var express = require("express");

var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Request recieved for:", req.url);
    next();
});

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/heroes', express.static('public'));
app.use('/dashboard', express.static('public'));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.status(404);
    res.send('404 file not found');
});

app.listen(4040, function() {
    console.log("yes: 4040");
});
```

The app I'm working on also needs to pass params, so if you need to do that, you will need middleware of this format:

```
app.get('/peopledetails/:uid', function(req, res){
    var uid = req.params.uid,
        path = req.params[0] ? req.params[0] : 'index.html';
    res.sendFile(path, {root: './public'});
});
```

Thanks to this stack question for the above: [Serve Static Files on a Dynamic Route using Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569181/serve-static-files-on-a-dynamic-route-using-express).

Thanks for the help, folks.