# ExpressJS Serve static files within request function

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I'm currently serving static files like this:

```
app.use('/javascripts', express.static(join(__dirname + '/assets/javascripts')));
```

and it works as expected.

What I would like to do is to use the user session to serve static files depending on the session. I've tried this:

```
app.use('/javascripts', (req: Request, res: Response, next) =>{
    if(req.session.auth){
        express.static(join(__dirname + '/auth/javascripts'))
    } else{
        express.static(join(__dirname + '/assets/javascripts'))
    }
});
```

but it doesn't serve the files. Can someone explain why it doesn't work and how I can achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: A middleware function (the second argument of `.use()`) should process the request and call `next()`, so this code does nothing. Check out the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569181/serve-static-files-on-a-dynamic-route-using-express - what you're trying to do is very similar.

Comment: Works like a charm! Please answer so I can accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A middleware function (the second argument of `.use()`) should process the request and call `next()`, so this code does nothing.

What you need is to just have a dynamic route (instead of middleware) that redirects to the correct static directory according to `req.session.auth`:

```
app.get('/javascripts/*', function(req, res){
    if(req.session.auth){
        res.sendfile(req.params[0], {root: './auth/javascripts'});
    } else {
        res.sendfile(req.params[0], {root: './assets/javascripts'});
    } 
});
```